# How to import an eclipse based project from GitHub into Intellij properly

Tags: eclipse, maven, github, intellij-idea, import

I want to import a maven project from GitHub into intellij which in of itself I know how to do however, the project this time was created initially also as an eclipse project and I want to be able to work on it in idea while my team members work on it in eclipse without causing conflicts due to differing project file structures. How can this be done?

When checking it out in Intellij it does ask me if I want to create a project from it and select yes but next, it asks whether to create the project from the existing sources vs from external model. From the external model option it allows me to pick eclipse or maven but not both. Do I just create from existing sources? Which is my best option to do this without screwing it up for the others when I commit and push my changes?

I understand that the easy answer might be: "just use eclipse" however, I think the answer on how to properly do this could be useful later. Not only me but also for others who want to work with the IDE they are most familiar and productive with and not mess with the workflow.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When [importing an Eclipse project into IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-from-eclipse-page-1.html), you have the option to:

- Create module files near .classpath files
- Keep project and module files in

The idea is to keep your `*.iml` file concurrently with your Eclipse `.project/.classpath` (and you can [keep them in sync](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59944389#ImportingaProjectfromEclipse-6.ChoosewhethertokeepIntelliJIDEAandEclipseProjectsinSync)).
That way, you can open the project in both IDE.